# Not able to create DSN for oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to create dsn for oracle, as the procedure I know is like that goto Control Panel → Administrative tools → Data Source(ODFC) → UserDSN and the add.

After that we have select OracleXE and fill the remaining parameters.

But I am not able to find any OracleXE while adding. Only SQL server is there. I think OracleXE also has to be there. I don't know why it is not showing oracleXE. Please let me know the reason, because without oracleXE I am not able to create DSN.

Comment: Is the XE a 32-bit or 64-bit app?  Are you on a 64-bit OS?

Comment: yes i have 64bit OS, but i installed everything 32-bit (like jdk,eclipse etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Run the Datasource editor from this path c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.